# how to ignore a git folder but track a subfolder

Tags: git

I have a git repository and at this point I have tried numerous things in order to achieve the following:

the directory structure in my `git` repo is:

```
<project_name1>/bin/
<project_name1>/bin/data/
<project_name1>/src/
<project_name2>/bin/
<project_name2>/bin/data/
<project_name2>/src/
```

I want to use .gitignore in order to ignore everything in the bin folder, apart from the files in the bin data folder.

```
#ignore the bin folder...
/*/bin/*
#...but don't ignore anything in ./bin/data/ folder
!/*/bin/data/
!/*/bin/data/
```

the above fails, and this is one of the Many slight variations I have tried. But the problem persists. the folder `bin/data` and any files in the folder `bin/data/*` are ignored.

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: How does title and question are connected?

Comment: Have you read documentation on gitignore? What `*` is for at beginning of patterns?

Comment: @AlexeyTen hi there, now that you mentioned it I went back to the documentation to check for possible syntax errors. The only reference I found was on an example where "*" (=any folder/file name) follows a leading "/". So I updated my `.gitignore` definition above. Then I created a file and a folder in `<git_repo>/<proj_name1>/bin/data/`. The file was identified, but the folder was not by a `git status` operation.

Comment: Git doesn't track folders. Only files

Comment: @AlexeyTen can that be so? what if there are files in a folder though? do you have to explicitly track the folder name? this seems counter productive

Comment: It will track these files (if you don't completely ignore folder they are in).

Comment: After your edit, do you have both projects in one repo?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to almost all ignore trouble is

```
git check-ignore -v $path
```

The rules you've shown won't exclude that folder. I"m betting you've got a `bin/` rule somewhere in a global or repo excludes list.

Comment: hi there, the command does not return anything on output. I tried `cd <repo base folder>` then the command you mention. I also tried it in other subfolders, to no avail. I read the documentation but it says nothing. should I expect to see something somewhere?

Comment: for `$path` you should put some path in that folder -- it doesn't have to exist, try `git check-ignore -v bin/data/foo`.

Comment: why do you "bet" i've got a `bin/` rule somewhere? I have pasted the relevant `gitignore` part above. is there another file I should consider?

Comment: Well, if the `bin/data` contents really are being ignored you could read the docs on gitignore or do what I suggest doing, either way you'll have your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you tried, but this repository directory structure:

```
a/bin/bar
a/bin/data/foo
b/bin/data/foo
```

With this `.gitignore`:

```
/*/bin/*
!/*/bin/data/
```

Will lead to this status output after using `git add -A`:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   a/bin/data/foo
    new file:   b/bin/data/foo
```

Speaks: `a/bin/bar` won't be tracked while the files in `bin/data` will.

---

I'm using git version 1.9.4. For further information take a look at the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore).